# Find generating function using Dynkin's formula : How is it possible since $f(x)=e^{xu}$ is not compact supported?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

(It looks long, but it's not). The aim of the question is to understand **why can we apply Dynkins formula to $f(x)=e^{ux}$ whereas $f$ is no compact supported ?**

Here a lemma and Dynkin's formula and a lemma :

[image]

[image]

### **Here the application**

[image]

### **Question**

1) First, at the red cross, I don't understand $f(X(t),t)=f(x)=e^{ux}$. It doesn't make any sense, does it ?

2) Then, how can we apply Dynkin's formula to $f(x)=e^{ux}$ whereas ti's not compact supported ?

Comment: The assumption $f \in C_0^2$ is not needed, it suffices to have $f \in C_b^2$. You can see this by applying Itô's formula (which holds for $C_b^2$-functions) or by using a truncation argument

Comment: @saz: thanks for your answer. but $f(x)=e^{ux}$ is not bounded... and also, my dynkin's formula is wrong ? why they use $C_0^2$ is $C_b^2$ is sufficient ?

Comment: As Saz said, Ito's formula works in a more general setting, i.e. $f\in C^2$

What we need in this example is for the integral $\int_0^t s^2 \mathbb{E}[f(X(s)] ds$ to converge.

We also need some argument to swap the expectation and the integral, which is usually dominated convergence theorem

As for the red cross, here it would really be: $f(X(t),t) = e^{X(t)u}$

Comment: @user657324 Right, it's not bounded, sorry about that... essentially Dynkin's formula works whenever all the appearing expressions are well-defined. Set $$\tau_r := \inf\{t; |X_t| \geq r\}$$ then Itô's formula yields $$\mathbb{E}f(X_{t \wedge \tau_r}) - \mathbb{E}f(X_0) = \mathbb{E} \int_{(0,t \wedge \tau_r)} Lf(X_s) \, ds$$ for any $f \in C^2$. Now we would like to let $r \to \infty$; for this we will need certain integrability assumptions, as GeorgeDewhirst already pointed out.